# Restsharp getting gateway timeout when postman works fine

Tags: timeout, postman, restsharp

Is there any reason a postman post request would work but the very same restsharp code gateway times out? I can still get the token just fine through restsharp, but when I try one request, it times out.

Comment: Could you give a bit more info about the problem, requests that you used in the Postman and in the Restsharp?

Comment: It's a post request to https://api.elliemae.com/encompass/v1/loanPipeline but requires a token which I cannot give out. In it, I provide a json formatted filter and it should return a list of strings to identify objects. The error I get is a gateway timeout as the status description with no content

Comment: That's still not enough. I is possible that you have not set the Restsharp requests in the same way that you did in Postman. So recheck that.

Comment: @randombeggar I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just battled with this error myself making a request to the exact same endpoint.

I had Restsharp installed via the NuGet Package Manager and then installed the Elli.Api package. Once I installed this package the timeout errors started, but were not happening before (Note: I was making direct API calls and not using the EllieMae dotnet bindings, but installing the Elli.Api package still caused timeouts).

What seemed to work for me is installing the Elli.Api package, then uninstalling Restsharp and reinstalling it. Requests seemed to function normally after this.

One other note: the Restsharp package I used was 106.2.2 both when I uninstalled it *and* when I reinstalled it.

EDIT: Doing this seems to cause various errors when you try to use the dotnet bindings (such as a missing method error when trying to use GetAccessToken).

Comment: To whom it may concern, I opened a ticket with Ellie Mae regarding the missing method exception and they are working on a solution.

Comment: I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com @rmgt